# Hamiltonian Cycle and vertex degrees

Tags: real-analysis, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Assume we have a graph $G=(V,E)$. Denote by $C$ a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.

Is it true to say that the degree of every vertex in $C$ is $2$, and for every vertex in $C$ its degree on $G$ is also $2$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: The first assertion is true by the definition of the Hamiltonian cycle. The second is not true . Consider two vertices connected with three different edges.

Comment: @BazyliZuczek You are right. Assuming that $G$ is also simple, than my statement is correct, right?

Comment: Unfortunately simplicity does not help. Consider a square with one diagonal added. Then two vertices have degree 3.

Comment: @BazyliZuczek Great! Thank you for that! :)